# AVD emulator opens previous expo project instead of current

Tags: react-native, expo, android-virtual-device

I am attempting to run my expo project on an Android virtual device.

I start by doing a
expo start

Then I open AVD Device manager and launch a device. Here I am getting an error "unable to locate ADB", but it still starts.

Finally I go to the web browser window that expo start had opened and click "Run on Android device/emulator"

The emulator then opens an older project instead of my existing project. What am I doing wrong? How can I open the existing project instead. That same browser window allows me to launch on my actual phone using the QR code and opens to the correct project.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up clearing expo app cache in the emulator and this addressed the issue.